# Snowflake store procedures CTE

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

I want to migrate uspGetBillOfMaterials store procedures in Adventurework2017 from sql to snowflake
. Code to create uspGetBillOfMaterials in SQL

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetBillOfMaterials]
    @StartProductID [int],
    @CheckDate [datetime]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Use recursive query to generate a multi-level Bill of Material (i.e. all level 1 
    -- components of a level 0 assembly, all level 2 components of a level 1 assembly)
    -- The CheckDate eliminates any components that are no longer used in the product on this date.
    WITH [BOM_cte]([ProductAssemblyID], [ComponentID], [ComponentDesc], [PerAssemblyQty], [StandardCost], [ListPrice], [BOMLevel], [RecursionLevel]) -- CTE name and columns
    AS (
        SELECT b.[ProductAssemblyID], b.[ComponentID], p.[Name], b.[PerAssemblyQty], p.[StandardCost], p.[ListPrice], b.[BOMLevel], 0 -- Get the initial list of components for the bike assembly
        FROM [Production].[BillOfMaterials] b
            INNER JOIN [Production].[Product] p 
            ON b.[ComponentID] = p.[ProductID] 
        WHERE b.[ProductAssemblyID] = @StartProductID 
            AND @CheckDate >= b.[StartDate] 
            AND @CheckDate <= ISNULL(b.[EndDate], @CheckDate)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT b.[ProductAssemblyID], b.[ComponentID], p.[Name], b.[PerAssemblyQty], p.[StandardCost], p.[ListPrice], b.[BOMLevel], [RecursionLevel] + 1 -- Join recursive member to anchor
        FROM [BOM_cte] cte
            INNER JOIN [Production].[BillOfMaterials] b 
            ON b.[ProductAssemblyID] = cte.[ComponentID]
            INNER JOIN [Production].[Product] p 
            ON b.[ComponentID] = p.[ProductID] 
        WHERE @CheckDate >= b.[StartDate] 
            AND @CheckDate <= ISNULL(b.[EndDate], @CheckDate)
        )
    -- Outer select from the CTE
    SELECT b.[ProductAssemblyID], b.[ComponentID], b.[ComponentDesc], SUM(b.[PerAssemblyQty]) AS [TotalQuantity] , b.[StandardCost], b.[ListPrice], b.[BOMLevel], b.[RecursionLevel]
    FROM [BOM_cte] b
    GROUP BY b.[ComponentID], b.[ComponentDesc], b.[ProductAssemblyID], b.[BOMLevel], b.[RecursionLevel], b.[StandardCost], b.[ListPrice]
    ORDER BY b.[BOMLevel], b.[ProductAssemblyID], b.[ComponentID]
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 25) 
END;
```

I have already migrate all table from SQL to snowflake
I have try to do it in snowflake with code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc2(StartProductID float , CheckDate datetime) -- set default startproduct id = 1 and checkdate = '2008-04-30 00:00:00.000'
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS $$
retrieve_queries_sql = 'WITH BOM_CTE ("ProductAssemblyID", "ComponentID", "ComponentDesc", "PerAssemblyQty", "StandardCost", "ListPrice", "BOMLevel", "RecursionLevel")
    AS (
        SELECT b."ProductAssemblyID", b."ComponentID", p."Name", b."PerAssemblyQty", p."StandardCost", p."ListPrice", b."BOMLevel", 0 
        FROM "ADVENTUREWORKS2017"."PRODUCTION"."BillOfMaterials" b
            INNER JOIN "ADVENTUREWORKS2017"."PRODUCTION"."Product" p 
            ON b."ComponentID" = p."ProductID" 
        WHERE b."ProductAssemblyID" = 1
            AND '2008-04-30 00:00:00.000' >= b."StartDate" 
            AND '2008-04-30 00:00:00.000' <= IFNULL(b."EndDate", '2008-04-30 00:00:00.000')
        UNION ALL
        SELECT b."ProductAssemblyID", b."ComponentID", p."Name", b."PerAssemblyQty", p."StandardCost", p."ListPrice", b."BOMLevel", "RecursionLevel" + 1 -- Join recursive member to anchor
        FROM "BOM_CTE" cte
            INNER JOIN "PRODUCTION"."BillOfMaterials" b 
            ON b."ProductAssemblyID" = cte."ComponentID"
            INNER JOIN "PRODUCTION"."Product" p 
            ON b."ComponentID" = p."ProductID" 
        WHERE '2008-04-30 00:00:00.000' >= b."StartDate" 
            AND '2008-04-30 00:00:00.000' <= IFNULL(b."EndDate", '2008-04-30 00:00:00.000')
        )
    SELECT b."ProductAssemblyID", b."ComponentID", b."ComponentDesc", SUM(b."PerAssemblyQty") AS "TotalQuantity" , b."StandardCost", b."ListPrice", b."BOMLevel", b."RecursionLevel"
    FROM "BOM_CTE" b
    GROUP BY b."ComponentID", b."ComponentDesc", b."ProductAssemblyID", b."BOMLevel", b."RecursionLevel", b."StandardCost", b."ListPrice"
    ORDER BY b."BOMLevel", b."ProductAssemblyID", b."ComponentID"
';
retrieve_queries_result_set = snowflake.execute({sqlText: retrieve_queries_sql });

query_to_run = retrieve_queries_result_set.next().getColumnValue(1);

rs = snowflake.execute({sqlText: query_to_run})

var return_value = "";
if (rs.next())  {
      return_value += rs.getColumnValue(1);
      return_value += ", " + rs.getColumnValue(2);
      }
while (rs.next())  {
      return_value += "\n";
      return_value += rs.getColumnValue(1);
      return_value += ", " + rs.getColumnValue(2);
      }
  }
return return_value;
$$
```

But got error with sql statement var , can you guys help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using back ticks ` to wrap your SQL statement instead of single quotes '

Comment: Thanks for your help , actually it's quite easy if i have a little bit knowledge about js , all i have to do is add '\n\' after a single line in sql command , but thanks for your help <3

Comment: No problem. Yeah that is another way. I just find it easier to use the back tick so I don't have to worry about missing a new line character!